# Angular ADAL requires authentication for non authenticated routes

Tags: angularjs, adal.js

Scenario is AngularJS 1.6.5 SPA, c# WebAPI and Azure AD (AAD) for authentication. I'm using Angular-ADAL library to handle the authentication and angular-route to handle routes. Strange thing is that routes that CAN be anonymous (i.e. DO NOT require the `requireADLogin: true` in the route definition) but need to go to the backend (for example to get an image or to get data from the API), get intercepted by ADAL and never get to the backend/API.

My routes are defined like so, when I want a route protected:

```
.when('/clasesDeDocumento', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/mantenedores/clasesDeDocumento/clasesDeDocumento.html',
    controller: 'clasesDeDocumentoController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    requireADLogin: true,
    title: "clases de documentos"
})
```

And similar to the above, but without the `requiredADLogin: true` when not protected.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js):

> Routes that do not specify the  requireADLogin=true  property are added to the  anonymousEndpoints  array automatically.

Clicking on an unprotected link does not take you to the Azaure Authentication page, however the backend/API request gets intercepted and an error is thrown.

I have solved this (manually) adding an `anonymousEndpoints` array, but for larger applications, this would not be feasible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. The `requireADLogin` and `anonymousEndpoints` parameters are used for the different purpose.

The `requireADLogin` is used for the whether the routes are needle to protect. If it is true, the app will requires users to authenticate first before they can access the route.

The `anonymousEndpoints` parameter is used help the adal library to determine whether the `$http` service required to inject the token. And by default, the route URL will be added into the `anonymousEndpoints` if we doesn't specify the `requireADLogin` parameter to true(refer the [routeChangeHandler](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/238dd662722b053f199944a3171d2783ad8f4912/lib/adal-angular.js#L240L262)).